# Can't drop temp table in Postgres function: "being used by active queries in this session"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression

It is expected to now take in a table called `waypoints` and follow through the function body.

```
drop function if exists everything(waypoints);
create function everything(waypoints) RETURNS TABLE(node int, xy text[]) as $$
BEGIN
    drop table if exists bbox;
    create temporary table bbox(...);
    insert into bbox
        select ... from waypoints;

    drop table if exists b_spaces;
    create temporary table b_spaces(
        ...
    );
    insert into b_spaces
        select ...

    drop table if exists b_graph; -- Line the error flags.
    create temporary table b_graph(
       ...
    );
    insert into b_graph
        select ...

    drop table if exists local_green;
    create temporary table local_green(
        ...
    );
    insert into local_green 
        ...

    with aug_temp as (
        select ...
    )
    insert into b_graph(source, target, cost) (
        (select ... from aug_temp) 
        UNION 
        (select ... from aug_temp)
    );

    return query
        with 
        results as (
            select id1, ... from b_graph -- The relation being complained about.
        ),
        pkg as (
            select loc, ...
        )
        select id1, array_agg(loc) 
        from pkg
        group by id1;
    return;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This returns `cannot DROP TABLE b_graph because it is being used by active queries in this session`

How do I go about rectifying this issue?

Comment: Why do you use temp tables? Are the temp tables supposed to be referenced outside the function also? Also: your version of Postgres is *always* part of the necessary details.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter because they are all just intermediates to get my final result. I'm using 9.3, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Also, are reads and writes from CTEs as fast as reads and writes from tables? Because when I made views, everytime I accesses the view, the view would be recalculated.

Comment: "take in a table called `waypoints`" .. makes no sense. If you know the table is called `waypoints`, you don't need a parameter. If you need a parameter for the table, you need dynamic SQL and things get more complicated. Don't confuse parameter name, parameter value and data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is rather obvious, you cannot drop a temp table while it is being used.

You might be able to avoid the problem by adding `ON COMMIT DROP`:

- [Temporary table and loops in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019369/temporary-table-and-loops-in-a-function/13019652#13019652)

However, this can probably be simpler. If you don't *need* all those temp tables to begin with (which I suspect), you can replace them all with CTEs (or most of them probably even with cheaper subqueries) and simplify to one big query. Can be plpgsql or just SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION everything(waypoints)
  RETURNS TABLE(node int, xy text[]) AS
$func$
   WITH bbox      AS (SELECT ... FROM waypoints)  -- not the fct. parameter!
    , b_spaces    AS (SELECT ... )
    , b_graph     AS (SELECT ... )
    , local_green AS (SELECT ... )
    , aug_temp    AS (SELECT ... )
    , b_graph2(source, target, cost) AS (
        SELECT ... FROM b_graph
        UNION ALL  -- guessing you really want UNION ALL
        SELECT ... FROM aug_temp
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT ... FROM aug_temp
       )
    , results     AS (SELECT id1, ... FROM b_graph2)
    , pkg         AS (SELECT loc, ... )
   SELECT id1, array_agg(loc) 
   FROM   pkg
   GROUP  BY id1
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Views are just storing a query ("the recipe"), not the actual resulting values ("the soup").

It's typically cheaper to use CTEs instead of creating temp tables.
**Derived tables in queries**, sorted by their typical overall performance (exceptions for special cases involving indexes). From slow to fast:

```
CREATE TABLE
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE
CREATE TEMP TABLE
CTE
subquery
```

[`UNION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-union.html) would try to fold duplicate rows. Typically, people really want `UNION ALL`, which just appends rows. Faster and does not try to remove dupes.

Comment: Awesome @Erwin. I see no RETURN(s) there, are they not necessary?

Comment: @Louis93: RETURN would be necessary in plpgsql, I switched to `LANGUAGE sql` for the simplified case. You can use plpgsql as well.

Comment: Hello - hopefully this is the last blocker. 

So in the `results` CTE, I invoke a function like so: `pgr_ksp('select * FROM b_graph')` to form `results`

However, I get this back: `relation "b_graph" does not exist`. Does b_graph have to be a table?

Comment: Also, I'm really grateful for your in-depth responses. I'm a little out of depth here and the pointers are really helpful.

Comment: If you are executing dynamic SQL, then yes, `b_graph` has to be a table. But what I see here is just horrible. Wide open for SQL injection ....

Comment: How would you refactor?

Comment: @Louis93: Read and understand first: http://bobby-tables.com/, http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860